# How to force HTTPS using .htaccess for example.com?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to force https for a site, but it only works if i type www.example.com, and not when i use example.com. Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then put these lines above HTTPS condition

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Change to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` no need to redirect to http before https